# Pandas change column value if greater than len

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to use an if statement to change values within a column if there length is greater than x

My csv data ..

```
  ID            Test_Case                                            TC_NUM
14581,dialog_testcase_4000.0134_mvp_not_understood-inprogress.xml,4000.0134
14582,dialog_testcase_4000.0135_mvp_not_understood-inprogress.xml,4000.0135
14583,dialog_testcase_4000.0136_mvp_not_understood-inprogress.xml,4000.0136
14584,dialog_testcase_4000.0137_mvp_not_understood_6.2.0-inprogress.xml,4000.01376.2.0
14585,dialog_testcase_4000.0138_mvp_not_understood_6.2.0-inprogress.xml,4000.01386.2.0
```

What I want:

```
  ID            Test_Case                                            TC_NUM
14581,dialog_testcase_4000.0134_mvp_not_understood-inprogress.xml,4000.0134
14582,dialog_testcase_4000.0135_mvp_not_understood-inprogress.xml,4000.0135
14583,dialog_testcase_4000.0136_mvp_not_understood-inprogress.xml,4000.0136
14584,dialog_testcase_4000.0137_mvp_not_understood_6.2.0-inprogress.xml,4000.0137
14585,dialog_testcase_4000.0138_mvp_not_understood_6.2.0-inprogress.xml,4000.0138
```

My current code is able to extract some of the right columns, but messes up if additional numbers are in there.

```
df1['TC_NUM'] = df1['TC_NUM'].str.replace(r'[^0-9.]+', '')

df1['TC_NUM'] = df1['TC_NUM'].str[:-1]
```

My thought/attempt as using an if statement to correct this.

```
if dfidtcnum(len['TC_NUM'] > 12):
    print "True"
```

Comment: `df1['TC_NUM'] = df1['TC_NUM'].str.replace(r'\.[^\.]{1,3}\.\d*$', '')` could work for what you have shown here, but it's not really a general solution. As long as the number between the second and third dots is between 1 to 3 digits, it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
print (df.TC_NUM.str.len() > 9)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: TC_NUM, dtype: bool


df['TC_NUM'] = df.TC_NUM.mask(df.TC_NUM.str.len() > 9, df.TC_NUM.str[:-5])
print (df)
      ID                                          Test_Case     TC_NUM
0  14581  dialog_testcase_4000.0134_mvp_not_understood-i...  4000.0134
1  14582  dialog_testcase_4000.0135_mvp_not_understood-i...  4000.0135
2  14583  dialog_testcase_4000.0136_mvp_not_understood-i...  4000.0136
3  14584  dialog_testcase_4000.0137_mvp_not_understood_6...  4000.0137
4  14585  dialog_testcase_4000.0138_mvp_not_understood_6...  4000.0138
```